HEAD presigned URL AWS SDK version 2
We are migrating from AWS SDK v1 to v2. In the old application, we were generating a HEAD presigned URL, and by executing that, the clients can read the metadata of the s3 object. But in version 2, I could not find a way to generate HEAD presigned URL (Anyway it exists for other verbs like GET GetObjectPresignRequest).
Can anyone help on this please?
